# Various ways for Implementing website registration and login + OpenID

Tags: authentication, registration

I'm looking for various ways to choose from in order to implement a non-ssl website registration/login system.

Is there any resource which lists and teaches some of the more popular and standard ones so I can choose the one which best suits my website's needs?
note that it doesn't really matter in what language, since I'm looking to "understand" the logic behind the implementation, so I can implement it myself.

Furthermore, What's the best resource in order to implement registration using "OpenID", I find the whole idea really great.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this ?

For Gmail
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

For Yahoo
http://developer.yahoo.com/bbauth/user.html

For MSN/Hotmail/Live
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the third party sign in sites are using some form of [oauth](http://oauth.net/).  Google, Facebook, OpenID, Twitter and many others use oauth.  oauth allows you to leverage someone else https server to perform your sign on.  This is win-win because the service like Google gets exposure for this.  So people are more likely to look at the services Google provides.  It is just about as secure and even has measures to prevent man in the middle attacks.

I have used oauth with Code Igniter for website sign ons.  I am also going to use this with my games I produce.  There are tons of examples [here](http://oauth.net/code/) for using with various programming languages both in an app and in a website.

**Edit:**
Warning!  Do not think the OpenAuth API from AOL has anything to do with oauth.  They are two different animals.  It gets even more confusing when people post about oauth calling it Open Auth.  I don't know if the name collision was on purpose, but I wish AOL would call it something else.  I spent some time thinking I could use AOL for login and found it was a proprietary API by AOL.